# Enable Ehcache for all entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

I'm using Spring Data JPA, Hibernate 4.3.10.Final, Ehcache on Wildfly 8.2. I want to test how the application server handle all my data in cache.

The question is : Is it possible to enable 2nd level cache for all scanned entities by default ?

Actually, I want to avoid to add `@Cache` on every entities (since the project have 100+).

**JPA properties**

```
... data source definition ...
<property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ALL" />
```

**Hibernate properties**

```
<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="1000000000"
                  eternal="true"
                  overflowToDisk="false"
                  diskPersistent="false"
                  diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
                  statistics="true"
                  >
    </defaultCache>
    <!-- 
    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
            eternal="false"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120">
            <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache> -->
</ehcache>
```

**EDIT:**
Tried `<prop key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode">ALL</prop>` as suggested by Dragan Bozanovic but it doesn't affect the process.

Here's the statistic log of a `SELECT e FROM MyEntity e` executed 2 times :

```
17:00:00,597 | INFO  | StatisticalLoggingSessionE:275  |  | Session Metrics {
    71157 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    145393 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    386233 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    822075 nanoseconds spent performing 41 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
17:00:00,597 | INFO  | StatisticalLoggingSessionE:275  |  | Session Metrics {
    63973 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    127262 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    282918 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    452598 nanoseconds spent performing 41 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

There's 41 rows returned, this is correct. But I see `41 L2C puts` 2 times, shouldn't it be `41 L2C puts` then `41 L2C hits` ?

Comment: It seems that configuration took effect - you are storing the entities to L2 cache. Regarding the statistics, try reading the entity by id (`entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id)`, or something equivalent in Spring Data). Here you are executing the query, and Hibernate must execute it in the database.

Comment: Works better with `.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true)` :). Thanks for the help !

Comment: Did you add that hint to the query? If so, do you really want the query to be cacheable? And why does it work, since you've set `use_query_cache` to `false`?

Comment: Yes I did. I switched `use_query_cache` to `true` for this. I don't want to have all queries cacheable but load all entities in cache to see memory use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache-mapping), add to your `persistence.xml`:

```
<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
```

If you don't configure Hibernate through `persistence.xml`, set the desired value in `javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode` configuration property.

However, you may want to achieve the same effect with:

```
<shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

This way you can annotate some entities with `@Cacheable(false)` if you later decide to turn off caching for them.

Comment: Actually, I don't have `persistence.xml` because I'm already using Spring to config/scan. That's why I have `<property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ALL" />` to replace `<shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>`. I'm currently trying to `.findAll()` entities and check cache after it's done to see if it works. Thanks for the `DISABLE_SELECTIVE` tip !

Comment: Ok, in that case you may want to use `javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode` config property. I mentioned it in my edited answer as well.